Why "require 'rational'" causes "cannot load such file -- rational" error in rails evn, and causes no error in irb env(just return false)
I've used a gem: mini_exiftool-2.11.0 in my rails app with bundler. And it manually require 'rational' in a file. Maybe it is for early ruby version when rational needed to be required for use. Now we know it is a part of the core. But it causes a loadError:
/Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:39:in `require': cannot load such file -- rational (LoadError)
    from <internal:/Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:39:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.17/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mini_exiftool-2.11.0/lib/mini_exiftool.rb:21:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:/Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:39:in `require'
    from <internal:/Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:39:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.17/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/mini_exiftool_vendored-9.2.7.v1/lib/mini_exiftool_vendored.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.17/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.2.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.17/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/.rbenv/versions/3.2.2/lib/ruby/3.2.0/bundler.rb:196:in `require'
    from /Users/57block/work/hobnob-web/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'

And This error should not be occurring because requiring it in irb just returns false, not eror:
~/work/hobnob-web [tom/ruby-3] $ irb
irb(main):001> require 'rational'
=> false
irb(main):002>

I don't know why the same require behaves differently and how to fix it.
ruby version: 3.2.2
rails version: 7.2

Add your ruby and rails versions to the question

@dbugger Updated as suggested. Thanks.

Please provide a MRE

This is not causing your issue but you might want to drop mini_exiftool_vendored-9.2.7.v1. It does not do much of anything other than contain a bundled version of the Exiftool that was released in April of 2013. (Current production version is 12.76). All that being said I am unable to reproduce your error Example

Possible workaround if you cannot figure it out: put an empty radional.rb file in the lib folder of your Rails app.
